# SQL query, generating several rows by a value in a field

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle database. Imaging I have a table with a row as following

```
 col1  |  col2  | col3
'Str1' | 'Str2' | 4
```

The value from col3=4 should generate 4 rows as following:

```
 col1  |  col2  | col3
'Str1' | 'Str2' | 1
'Str1' | 'Str2' | 2
'Str1' | 'Str2' | 3
'Str1' | 'Str2' | 4
```

After several hours in front of the screen and stil no luck - how can I create such a select query???

Answer (score 3):

You can do this if you create a sequence of integers.  Here is an approach:

```
with seq as (
      select level n from dual connect by level <= 100
     )
select t.col1, t.col2, seq.n
from t join
     seq
     on seq.n <= t.col3
```